# Add a "details" view to NextGEN Gallery?

Tags: wordpress, photo-gallery

I am working on a site with WordPress for a client who wants to showcase her products online, but does not want to sell them over the web. I have a simple photo gallery set up with the NextGEN Gallery plugin. Upon clicking the thumbnails in the gallery view, instead of simply showing them in a lightbox or their own page, I would like to add a "details" page for each photo - kind of like the individual product pages on a shopping site, but without any of the shopping functionality. Would it be possible to do this using NextGEN gallery or another plugin, or do I have to do it from scratch (and how would I do that)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because NextGen doesn't actually create a WordPress 'Page' to link the single image to, you may be better off using the built-in WordPress Galleries (You may of seen the [[gallery]](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) shortcode). When you upload an image to a page or post, WordPress stores that image as a post in the wp_posts table, alongside all your other posts and pages.. with a post_type of 'attachment', and adds it to a 'Gallery' for the post or page. You can manage the current gallery for any page or post by clicking the 'Add Media' icon above the text editor. While the [gallery] shortcode is quite limited, you can use code in your theme to display the gallery and images anyway you want.

If it was me, I would make a 'Products' page and individual 'Product' pages as child pages of 'Products' (or if you want more flexibility, use a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) for the products) and then upload all the product photos into the 'Product' page galleries (creating a gallery per product) - and setting the primary image as the '[Featured Image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)' for each product page. Then in your 'Products' page template (page-products.php) I would make a loop to display all the individual Product page's [featured images](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).. something like..

```
<?php
    //Add this to your 'Products' page temaplte, page-products.php
    $products = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ));
    while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post() ; ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail() ?>
        </a>
    <?php endwhile;
?>
```

That will create a list of the Product featured images, and you can use CSS to adjust the display - and each featured image will link to the individual product page.

Then in your individual Product pages (you can use a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) to target all of them), you can display the individual product gallery (like detail shots of the product) using [get_children()](http://codex.wordpress.org/get_children#Examples) or use [the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) again to display a larger close-up version of the primary photo. And of course, then you can use the post content of your individual product page to display the info text for each photo, like so:

```
<?php
    /* Template Name: Individual Product */
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        the_post_thumbnail();
        the_content();
    endwhile;
?>
```

To take it another step further, you could add all sorts of other data about the individual product with [custom meta boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/add_meta_box), and display them on the side of the page or something.. like 'Product Size', 'Color', 'Foo', 'Bar'.. anything really. Hope that helps!

Comment: Where do I put the code for the individual product template, and how do I tell my product pages to use that template?

Comment: Scooter, have a look here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Comment: Thank you James. My client changed her mind and doesn't want this anymore, but I've learned something.